# Image resizing in php? Can't get it to work

Tags: php, image

I have this code that I have tried creating and don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
    // SET ERROR FLAG
    $error = false;
    // MAKE SURE FILE IS AN IMAGE
    if (!list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {
        $error = true;
    } 
    // MAKE SURE FILE COMES FROM FORM
    if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {
        $error = true;
    }
    // MAKE SURE FILESIZE IS NOT OVER 1MB
    if (filesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']) > 1048576) {
        $error = true;
    }
    // TARGER TO SAVE FILE AND CHANGE FILENAME AND FILE TYPE
    $target = 'images/avatars/' . md5($user['id']) . '.gif';
    // IMAGE RATIO AND RESIZING
    $imgRatio = $width / $height;
    if ($imgRatio > 1) {
        $newWidth = 200;
        $newHeight = 200 / $imgRatio;
    } else {
        $newWidth = 200 * $imgRatio;
        $newHeight = 200;
    }
    $imgResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    $newImg = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
    $newImg = imagecopyresized($imgResized, $newImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    // SUCCESSFULL IMAGE UPLOAD
    if (!$error && move_uploaded_file($newImg, $target)) {
        echo '<p>Your avatar was uploaded successfully.</p>';
        // ERROR UPLOADING IMAGE
    } else {
        echo '<p>There was an error uploading your avatar.</p>';
    }
```

It always fails I cannot get the resizing to work, even a link to a good tutorial will suffice,

Happy new year!!

Comment: PHP error messages? Warning? Etc... You set the `$error` variable in multiple points. Just tell us where it is set to `FALSE`, so we can know where the problem is...

Comment: It fails just at the very end point when saving to the folder, and I am only uploading gifs so it is not the file type!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you use GD to open the temporary image file:

```
$newImg = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
$newImg = imagecopyresized($imgResized, $newImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
```

And then you try to move the temporary avatar file with `move_uploaded_file` without freeing GD resource and also discarding all the work done with GD (the resizing I mean, and I can add here you have to use *resample* instaead of *resize* method).

```
if (!$error && move_uploaded_file($newImg, $target)) {
```

The code moves the temporary uploaded file (currently opened by GD and however not physically altered by your GD work, so *not resized*) to the `$target` path.

**Edit**. Now I see more errors with your code. You cannot do:

```
$newImg = imagecopyresized($imgResized, $newImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
```

Because `imagecopyresized` do not returns anything but `true` or `false`. It simply copy one portion of a source image to a different destination resource. It do not return a resource itself!

**Finally**. The correct workflow to the what you want to do is:

- Check the uploaded file if it's ok for you (and you do it good, it seems).
- Create a `$img` GD resource opening the uploaded file with `imagecopyresized`.
- Create an empty destination resource `$newImg` with `imagecreatetruecolor`.
- Resize or resample using  `imagecopyresized` or `imagecopyresampled` to copy source image to destination resource.
- Save destination resource into a GIF file using `imagegif`.
- Discard temporary source uploaded image.

You can learn more googling something like *php gd resize uploaded images*. Tons of tutorial will be one click far from you.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks alright, however there could be a number reasons why it fails. Some debug output would be helpful. Some general pointers:

- check that the path for the `tmp_name` is set and readable
- check your php settings for `post_max_size`, it may be set very low or not set at all.
- in your code you are only handling gif type images (`imagecreatefromgif`), you may need to check for the filetype prior to reading from the image resource
- check that GD is properly installed in your php installation (`phpinfo();` in a php script or `php -i` from command line should display it as acticated)

That being sad, add some error messages to your output so we can help further.

Comment: Yes GD is definetely activated.